# An alternative sampling without replacement

Tags: sampling, resampling, importance-sampling, weighted-sampling

Consider a set $X := \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ with corresponding weights $p_1, \ldots, p_n$. Suppose we would like to draw $m < n$ distinct (i.e. unique) elements in a way that the probability of drawing a set $(x_{i_1}, \ldots, x_{i_m})$ is proportional to the product of corresponding weights, i.e.
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
p_{(i_1, \ldots , i_m)} :\propto p_{i_1} \cdots p_{i_m}.
\end{equation}
Since we are drawing among all sequences $(i_1, \ldots, i_m)$ with no duplicates, the normalizing constant is the sum over all such sequences:
$$\tag{2}
p_{(i_1, \ldots , i_m)} = \frac{p_{i_1} \cdots p_{i_m}}{\sum_{\substack{(j_1, \ldots, j_m) \\ \text{no duplicates}}} p_{j_1} \cdots p_{j_m}}.
$$
This is equivalent to a sampling scheme where one samples $m$ weighted elements **with** replacement and then rejects (and repeats) the entire sample if it contains at least one pair duplicate values.
Surprisingly (to me) this scheme is *not* equivalent to weighted sampling **without** replacement, i.e. where one sequentially samples first $i_1$ with weights, updates all remaining weights and then samples $i_2$, etc.

When $n$ is large, direct sampling by computing the denominator in (2) is practically impossible. Further, if $m$ is close to $n$ or if weights have a very non-uniform distribution, the rejection sampler may take very long before the sampling with replacement manages to draw a sample of $m$ distinct draws. Yet (1) has a simple structure, which perhaps could enable more efficient sampling.

**My question is:**  Is there a way to sample efficiently from this scheme? This could for instance be a sequential sample with some update of weights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are algorithms in the survey literature for what is called "$\pi$ps sampling" or "PPS sampling without replacement".  Most of these only get the marginal probabilities for individual observations to match what you want and the pairwise probabilities to be non-zero (which is still not entirely trivial).  The Conditional Poisson Sampling approach gets the joint probabilities as you want them (I think). It uses rejection, but in a different way.

The idea is to take probabilities $q_i$ and independently sample each observation or not with probability $q_i$, then accept the sample if the sample size turns out to be $m$.  The probability of getting the right sample size is going to be of order $m^{-1/2}$ -- if the probabilities were the same, the sample size would be Poisson with variance $m$, so the number of high-probability values it has would be of the order of $\sqrt{m}$.

The problem is computing the $q_i$. As you note, they are not the $p_i$, and computing them does seem to require computing the big messy denominator. It's not completely intractable if $m$ is small, but it is slow. [This](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1010091628740) is one reference.

A good book about algorithms for PPS sampling is the one by [Yves Tillé](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387308142); he also has [software](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampling/index.html)